# Overloading the style for "thesis" : final punctuation issues (in citedas, and between type and title)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

[In my first question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427231/formatting-issue-with-declarebibliographydriver-in-my-custom-biblatex-style-base) I covered the definition of the Bibliography driver, and now I'm almost done with the definition, thanks to the help of this forum.

GutNicolas, Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivil-prozessordnung, These, Bâle **,** 2014 (cité :Gut **,** These ).

I'd need to get this kind of bibliography :

Gut Nicolas, Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivil-prozessordnung, thèse, Bâle 2014 (cité :Gut-These ).

This means :

1. Change the delimiter in the cited as part
2. Change the delimiter in case of multiple location to " / "
3. Allows multiple location (builtin ?)
4. Remove the punctuation (,) in between the type, location and year part.
5. Change the use of "printfield{label}" to "printfield{type}"

### Question :

Which kind of parameter should I investigate ?

## Edit 1 - MWE instead of Extracts

Following the remark from @moewe, I edit this post to include a MWE.

**Main.Tex**

```
% MweBiblatex Swiss Legal
\documentclass{article}

% Needed by Biblatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=biblatex-xawi, language=french, bibencoding=UTF8, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{main.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Test de la bibliographie}
\printbibliography
\section{Tests de citation}
\nocite{*}
\subsection{Thèse}
\cite{gut}
\end{document}
```

**Main.bib**

```
@thesis{gut,
  author      = {Gut, Nicolas},
  title       = {Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivilprozessordnung},
  date        = {2014},
  location    = {Bâle},
  label       = {These}
}

@thesishabilitation{gut2,
    author      = {Gut, Nicolas},
    title       = {Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivilprozessordnung},
    date        = {2017},
    location    = {Berne},
    label       = {Forderungsklage}
}

@thesis{other,
    author      = {Other, Nicolas},
    title       = {A title for a thesis},
    date        = {2017},
    location    = {Berne}
}
```

**biblatex-xawi.cbx**

```
% PREAMBULE / REGLES GENERALES
\ProvidesFile{biblatex-xawi.cbx}[2018/04/13 v1.0 alpha]

\RequireCitationStyle{authortitle}

% --- --- Formatage général des citations --- --- %
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}

% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---%
% --- Formatage de la citation spécifique dans les citations --- %

% Definition de la partie "Labeltitle"
\DeclareLabeltitle{%
  \field{label}
  \field{shorttitle}
  \field{title}
  \field{maintitle}
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}
       {\ifsingletitle
          {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
       \setunit{\nametitledelim}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifsingletitle\AND
                 \(\iffieldundef{prenote}\OR\value{citecount}>1\)}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{%
      \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
      \addspace\bibopenparen}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}

\endinput
```

**biblatex-xawi.bbx**

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex-xawi.bbx}[2018/04/13 v1.1 alpha)]

% Depencances
\RequireBiber[2]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authortitle}

% Localisation
\NewBibliographyString{
    thesis,
    habilthesis
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
    citedas = {cité},
    thesis = {Thèse}
    habilthesis = {Thèse d'habilitation}
}

% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---%
% --- --- Setting default options --- --- %

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    maxbibnames=99, % nombre max. de noms pour les entrées
    maxcitenames=4, % nombre max. de noms pour les citations
    mincrossrefs=1, % nombre min pour les références croisées
    bibwarn=false, % avertissement uniques pour les entrés bibliographiques
    dashed=false, % Nom entier même si répétition
    singletitle=true, 
    uniquename=full,
    uniquelist=true
}

% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---%
% --- --- Formatage général des citations & bibliogryphies --- --- %
% Formatage global :
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

% Format des séparateurs entre les noms: des slash
% \DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
% \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\addspace}
% \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%

% Dans les citations, pas d'espaces entre les slash (contrairement à la bibliographie)
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\ifcitation{\slash}{\addnbspace\slash\addspace}}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Remove all possible shorthand
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244714/how-to-disable-the-use-of-shorthands-in-biblatex
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{shorthand}{\def\NewValue{}}


% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---%
% --- --- Pilote de bibliographie pour Thèse et Thèse d'habilitation --- --- %
% Formatage du style par défaut

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{location}{#1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{label}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{citedas}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% 
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{thesis}
      \step[fieldset=type, fieldvalue=thesis]
    }
    \map{
      \step[typesource=thesehabilitation, typetarget=thesis, final]
      \step[fieldset=type, fieldvalue=habilthesis]
    }
  }


% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---%
% --- Formatage de la citation spécifique dans la bibliographie --- %
% format : (cité : Auteur-label)
% Voir aussi partie "CBX" pour la partie "citation"

\newbibmacro{citedas:cite}{%
  \begingroup
    \delimcontext{cite}%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
    \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
    \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
    \undef\cbx@lasthash
    \undef\cbx@lastyear
    \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \endgroup
}

\newbibmacro{citedas}{%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}{
        \printtext[parens] {%
            \bibstring{citedas}%
            \addcolon\space
            \usebibmacro{citedas:cite}
        }
    }
}

\endinput % seulement à la fin
```

Comment: Please post the full `.bbx` and `.cbx` files so we know what we are talking about. It would also help if you could add a short `.tex` document with an example `.bib` entry of a `@thesis` that uses your custom styles.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I don't see any code at all.

Comment: You're far from stupid, but much faster than my edition skills. I needed to cut through my current version to isolate the relevant part

Comment: Ah OK, I thought you'd show us the entire thing.

Comment: Well, my full style contains non-MWE relevant things. Among other, other entry type and drivers, conditional bibliography, as per my others posts here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427231/formatting-issue-with-declarebibliographydriver-in-my-custom-biblatex-style-base or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427906/user-defined-printbibliography-with-conditional-formatting-on-count-of-entry-typ)

Comment: Fair enough, but it might be good to have an overview over everything you have so far. I noticed for example that you did not take into account all changes I suggested, so I thought it might be useful to see the entire thing and to rework it a bit.

Comment: BTW: Is it 'thése', 'thèse' or 'these'? And do you want to capitalise that word even after a comma?

Comment: Well, I believed I took all of your changes into account, but I must admit that I play around to understand the effect of each variable. And frankly, I totally don't understand the part "citedas:cite" & "textcite". For the format, it is thèse and as there is a comma, it shouldn't be capitalized. And I did a typo, the "thèse" should have a "," on both side, I'll edit it now. I believe the mix-up with These/Thèse comes from the fact that the driver uses Label and not the Type field, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think we had this before `\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\textendash}` is what you need.
2. As for the names, where you use `multinamedelim` and `finalnamedelim` you now need

   ```
   \DeclareDelimFormat{multilistdelim}{\addnbspace\slash\addspace}
   \DeclareDelimAlias{finallistdelim}{multilistdelim}
   ```
3. Is already possible. `location` is a list field and you can give multiple locations separated by `and`: `location = {Berne and Bâle},`
4. This is done in the `location+date` macro.
5. Done.

### `example.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=biblatex-xawi, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{DrueyComte,
  author      = {Druey, Jean-Nicolas and Comte, Alfred Leopold},
  title       = {Grundriss des Erbrechts},
  edition     = 6,    
  date        = {2016},
  location    = {Berne}
}

@book{Druey,
  author      = {Druey, Jean-Nicolas},
  title       = {Titre au hasard},
  date        = {2016},
  edition     = 2,
  location    = {Berne},
  label       = {Druey-Test}
}

@thesis{gut,
  author      = {Gut, Nicolas},
  title       = {Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivilprozessordnung},
  date        = {2014},
  location    = {Bâle},
  label       = {These}
}

@habilthesis{gut2,
    author      = {Gut, Nicolas},
    title       = {Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivilprozessordnung},
    date        = {2017},
    location    = {Berne and Bâle},
    label       = {Forderungsklage}
}

@thesis{other,
    author      = {Other, Nicolas},
    title       = {A title for a thesis},
    date        = {2017},
    location    = {Berne}
}

@message{MessageCPC,
    title       = {Message du Conseil fédéral du 28 juin 2006 relatif au code de procédure civile
suisse (CPC)},
    note        = {FF 2006 p. 6841 ss},
    label       = {Message CPC}
}
@thesis{habilthesis2,
  author = {Author Habilitation},
  title = {Title Thése Habilitation},
  date = {2014},
  type = {habilthesis},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}

\section{Expectation}
This test contains a citation to a message as well as several authors documents. Here are the expectation for citation :
\begin{itemize}
    \item book single author : "\textsc{Druey}"
    \item book multi-authors  : "\textsc{Druey/Comte}"
    \item message : "Message CPC"
\end{itemize}

When displayed in the bibliography, this item should become :

Message du Conseil fédéral du 28 juin 2006 relatif au code de procédure civilesuisse (CPC), FF 2006 p. 6841 ss (cité : \textsc{Message CPC})

\section{Test}

This is a series of citation to regular type, and a message at the very end. book single author : \cite{Druey}, \cite{DrueyComte}

If there are both type of data, then the table of content must be split in 2 parts, the first for all the non-message elements, the second for . The 2 parts must have subtitle (subsection) which should not appear in the table of content.

Test of citation message : \cite{MessageCPC}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### `biblatex-xawi.bbx`

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex-xawi.bbx}[2018/04/25 v1.2 alpha]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authortitle}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    maxbibnames=99, % nombre max. de noms pour les entrées
    maxcitenames=4, % nombre max. de noms pour les citations
    mincrossrefs=1, % nombre min pour les références croisées
    bibwarn=false, % avertissement uniques pour les entrés bibliographiques
    dashed=false, % Nom entier même si répétition
    singletitle=true, 
    uniquename=full,
    uniquelist=true,
}
\NewBibliographyString{thesis,habilthesis}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  citedas     = {cit\'e},
  thesis      = {th\`ese},
  habilthesis = {th\`ese d'habilitation},
}

% Formatage de la table
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\addspace}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%

\DeclareDelimFormat{multilistdelim}{\addnbspace\slash\addspace}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finallistdelim}{multilistdelim}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}


\newbibmacro{citedas:cite}{%
  \begingroup
    \delimcontext{cite}%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
    \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
    \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
    \undef\cbx@lasthash
    \undef\cbx@lastyear
    \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \endgroup
}

\newbibmacro{citedas}{%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{citedas}%
       \addcolon\space
       \usebibmacro{citedas:cite}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{citedas}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{citedas}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{message}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{citedas}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% If you must ...
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{shorthand}{\def\NewValue{}}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=habilthesis, typetarget=thesis, final]
      \step[fieldset=type,          fieldvalue=habilthesis]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{thesis}
      \step[fieldset=type, fieldvalue=thesis]
    }
  }
}

\endinput % <- only at the very end!
```

### `biblatex-xawi.cbx`

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex-xawi.cbx}[2018/04/25 v1.2]

\RequireCitationStyle{authortitle}
%\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{singletitle,uniquename,uniquelist,autocite=inline}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\textendash}

\DeclareLabeltitle{%
  \field{label}
  \field{shorttitle}
  \field{title}
  \field{maintitle}
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}
       {\ifsingletitle
          {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
       \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifsingletitle\AND
                 \(\iffieldundef{prenote}\OR\value{citecount}>1\)}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{%
      \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
      \addspace\bibopenparen}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}

\endinput
```

Comment: Indeed for (1) it was part of some comments in another message. This line triggers a warning "Package biblatex Warning: Delimiter 'nametitledelim' in context '' already defined, overwriting.". Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: @XaWi That is only a warning that can be safely ignored. Newer versions of `biblatex` do not issue a warning in these cases any more: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/621

Comment: And another question, why do we need a starred \DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1} but a normal. plain \DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\textendash} ?

Comment: @XaWi The star is needed if you want to overwrite type-specific definitions (type-specific definitions are made using the optional argument). `citetitle` has type-specific defaults, so these need to be reset with the starred version. `\DeclareDelimFormat` is similar, but there the starred version erases context-specific definitions. There are context-specific definitions of `nametitle` and we don't want to overwrite those.